# Can Fortify identify the servlet filter?

Tags: xss, fortify

I used the filter to fix the XSS.  But when i scan my codes using fortify software, the number of XSS issues didn't change. Did i miss something? or Fortify cannot recognize the filter? Here are my filter codes:

```
public final class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    super(servletRequest);
}

public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter) {

  String[] values = super.getParameterValues(parameter);
  if (values==null)  {
              return null;
      }
  int count = values.length;
  String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             encodedValues[i] = cleanXSS(values[i]);
   }
  return encodedValues;
}

public String getParameter(String parameter) {
      String value = super.getParameter(parameter);
      if (value == null) {
             return null;
              }
      return cleanXSS(value);
}

public String getHeader(String name) {
    String value = super.getHeader(name);
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    return cleanXSS(value);

}

private String cleanXSS(String value) {
    System.out.println("filter  : " + value);
    //System.out.println("afterfilter  : " + (isNotEmptyOrNull(value) ? StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(value) : value));
    //return isNotEmptyOrNull(value) ? StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(value) : value; 
    if(isNotEmptyOrNull(value)){
        value = value.replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
        value = value.replaceAll("\\(", "&#40;").replaceAll("\\)", "&#41;");
        value = value.replaceAll("'", "&#39;");
        value = value.replaceAll("eval\\((.*)\\)", "");
        value = value.replaceAll("[\\\"\\\'][\\s]*javascript:(.*)[\\\"\\\']", "\"\"");
        value = value.replaceAll("script", "");
    }
    System.out.println("afterfilter  : " +value);
    return value;
}
public static boolean isNotEmptyOrNull(String string) {
    if (string != null && !"".equals(string.trim())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Fortify doesn't have a rule for your `cleanXSS` method. What you will have to do is to write a custom rule, specifically a "data flow cleanse rule". This will let fortify know that any data that enters and then returned from this method will be safe from XSS.

However after looking at you XSS filter, I have to inform you that it's incomplete and will not take in to account all possible XSS vectors. I recommend that you use OWASP ESAPI's XSS filter. Fortify already has a rules for ESAPI.

Comment: I'm going to also add that any XSS solution that relies *soley* on an XSS filtering is guaranteed to be incomplete.  As long as XSS validation is conducted with regular expressions, there will *always* be at least one input that will slide through.